# Ошибка при attach модели к другому контексту данных

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Получаю ошибку. От каких то моделей получаю, от каких то - нет, разницы между ними не нашел, закономерности тоже.

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property
> value(s) of 'UserReq.IdSession' on one end of a relationship do not
> match the property value(s) of 'Truck.MobileSessionIdSession' on the
> other end.

Место возникновения ошибки:

```
context.Trucks.Attach(truck);
context.Entry(truck).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

У объекта `truck` типа `Truck` есть объект `MobileSession` типа `UserReq` где первичный ключ это `UserReq.IdSession` и соответственно `Truck.MobileSessionIdSession`.

В момент возникновения этой ошибки `truck.MobileSession == null`, я не могу понять почему она возникает.
Данный код используется внутри цикла, и моделей у кого `truck.MobileSession == null` достаточно много, но исключение происходит без закономерности, иногда модель проходит цикл без проблем, иногда та же самая модель выдает указанное выше исключение. Помогите)

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что исключение возникает именно из-за той сущностей, которую вы аттачите? Если что, команда `Attach` добавляет весь граф зависимых сущностей, и среди них могут быть и другие сущности `Truck`...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Вы имеете ввиду, что у сущностей Truck могут быть пути еще к каким ни будь сущностям Truck? Если да, то - нету таких зависимостей.

Comment: @PavelMayorov вы оказались правы. Есть такая зависимость. Как правильно поступить в такой ситуации?